# PHP 7.2 yum installation on Centos 7 misses libargon2.so

Tags: centos7, yum, php7

Command:

```
yum install php php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-zip php-fileinfo php-mbstring
```

Gives following error:

```
Error: Package: php-cli-7.2.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           Requires: libargon2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-7.2.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           Requires: libargon2.so.0()(64bit)
```

I have installed php earlier versions to Centos 7 before, but never encountered such a problem.

Where to start resolving this?

Centos 7 is a clean install, httpd and mariadb installed without problems.

I have tried:

yum clean all

yum distro-sync

Edit: PHP71 installed nicely, but I still need PHP72 in longer run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package you are missing is named libargon2, and it is in the `epel` repository. It was previously in `remi` until it was added to `epel`, at which point remi removed it from his repo.

In order to use the `remi-php72` repo, you must also enable the `remi` and `epel` repos, but one or both of these are disabled on your system.

Enable the `remi` and `epel` repos and try again.

Comment: Because secure password hashes are a good idea for everyone :)

Comment: I mean, why they move stuff around and break things? Your answer explains, why I could upgrade my PHP71 to PHP72 without this problem.

Comment: Most people would already have EPEL enabled, so wouldn't have noticed when they made this change. I didn't notice on any of my web servers. It's not well documented, but remi repo does require EPEL to be enabled.

Comment: @MichaelHampton "remi-safe" and "epel" should be enough for dependencies. Notice: remi-release have a dependency on epel-release, which make this requirement explicit.

Comment: @RemiCollet Some people don't use the remi-release RPM and just create .repo files manually. For instance, if they are using configuration management like Ansible to mangle their systems, they might just install the corresponding .repo file and not also install remi-release RPM afterward.